# Fastest way to make performance-critical method call polymorphic in C++?

Tags: c++, performance, polymorphism

I have the following problem. The class A has a set of methods compute1(), compute2(), compute3()... each having deeply nested loop where some performance-critical method is called. Depending on run-time conditions this method should be either func1() or func2():

```
class A {
public:
   void compute1(){
       for(i...)
         for(j...)
           for(k...)
             // call func1(i,j,k) or func2(i,j,k)
   }

   void compute2(){
       for(i...)
         for(j...)
           for(k...)
             // call func1(i,j,k) or func2(i,j,k)
   }
   ....
}
```

The call to func() is so performance-critical that no if statement inside func is acceptable. The number of compute() methods is large so making separate methods for each func is also not an option. Making func() virtual also doesn't work for performance reasons.
Due to design reasons I don't want to make class A a template (it is huge and contains tons of logic, so I don't want to put all this into a header file).

Are there any other solutions of this problem? It looks rather common to have several "backends" which are switched at runtime but I can't find an acceptable to way to achieve this...

Comment: Have you measured your performance? `virtual` methods are rarely ever a bottleneck these days. The Compiler sometimes inlines them where possible, and where not possible, the CPU's branch predictor and i-cache will eliminate the measurable costs depending on your access patterns... So, still, what's your measurement??

Comment: Before worrying about performance, ***measure***! Is the code you think really a bottleneck? Is it the bottleneck you *think* it is? Don't just dismiss solutions because of something you think might be a problem, always measure and profile first.

Comment: Define 'doesn't work for performance reasons'. It's only an extra indirection, and far faster than any of the alternatives you've contemplated. The obvious alternative is to make the decision outside the loop, if you can, i.e. write two sets of loops per method. Or a template: you don't have to put all the template implementation logic into a header file, so that objection is spurious.

Comment: two questions: a) what is the criterion for selecting func1 or func2 to be called? (i.e. is it dependant on i, j or k), and b) are i, j and k independent? If so there is an argument for parallelism.

Comment: @WhiZTiM The problem here is that the method is called billions of times, so even a small overhead is not tolerable. From what I measured virtual method gives ~2 times slower execution.

Comment: @EJP could please explain how can you put the body of template method in cpp file? From what I know this is not allowed.

Comment: @Richard Hodges it is already parallelized with OpenMP. func1 or func2 is independent on i,j,k and actually selected before calling the method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A possible way would be to have the methods `compute1()`, etc. use templates themselves. The template would be used only to choose the appropriate inner function to call. For example :

```
template <typename FuncTrait>
void A::compute1(FuncTrait trait)
{
    for (...)
      choose_func(trait);
}

struct trait_1 {};

template <>
void choose_func<trait_1>(trait_1)
{
    func1();
}
```

A possible way to invoke `compute1()`:

```
a.compute1(trait_1());
```

Comment: An variant of this would be to accept a reference to `func1` or `func2` itself as template argument: `template <void (&)(int, int, int)>`